# 500 Server Error on Localhost on Laptop - Works fine on other desktop machines

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, yii

for a project we have been working on we have moved it onto a laptop so work can be done at home.

The issue we are having is that the server is giving us a 500 server error on the laptop machine, but works perfectly fine on every desktop we have tested it on.

the htaccess. files are all the same, error logs don't bring up anything noticeable (except the 500 error in the console on the login form which is where it first falls over).

We are using the yii framework and even with all error reporting turned off it still refuses to work. All permissions are fine and the the entire project has been downloaded off our git machines.

We are running virtual hosts and sub domains but even accessing straight from the folder there is no luck.

httpd.conf and vhosts are also, exactly the same.

Is there anything that would flag up differences on two machines?

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

the erorr coming from the error log

```
[Thu Nov 12 12:21:16.002251 2015] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 6961] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Nov 12 12:21:16.024984 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 6961] AH00163: Apache/2.4.12 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1m PHP/5.6.8 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Nov 12 12:21:16.025061 2015] [core:notice] [pid 6961] AH00094: Command line: '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/httpd -E /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/logs/error_log -D SSL -D PHP'
```

error in console

POST http://m/site/login 500 (Internal Server Error)send @ jquery.js:9631jQuery.extend.ajax @ jquery.js:9176$.fn.yiiactiveform.validate @ jquery.yiiactiveform.js:357(anonymous function) @ jquery.yiiactiveform.js:96
jquery.js:9631 POST http://m/site/login 500 (Internal Server Error)send @ jquery.js:9631jQuery.extend.ajax @ jquery.js:9176$.fn.yiiactiveform.validate @ jquery.yiiactiveform.js:357(anonymous function) @ jquery.yiiactiveform.js:145jQuery.event.dispatch @ jquery.js:4641elemData.handle @ jquery.js:4309

Comment: What about the Apache version?

Comment: no error log for the 500. Apache 2.4.9 / 2.4.10 on desktops. 2.4.12 on laptop machine.

Comment: Do you have all the same mods set up in Apache, and all the same extensions enabled for PHP?

Comment: Can you test a single PHP file to see if it's your code or Apache? Just add some simple echo and a `die()` in the main PHP file and see if you still get the 500.

Comment: Other projects work fine on the localhost.

Comment: "even with all error reporting turned off it still refuses to work" Turning error reporting off has no effect on whether errors _happen_. You just don't see any information about them. Instead, turn all error reporting _on_, then generate a 500, then look at your error logs.

Comment: Yep. The one error Ive been able to grab from the logs is [Thu Nov 12 12:21:16.002251 2015] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 6961] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Nov 12 12:21:16.024984 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 6961] AH00163: Apache/2.4.12 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1m PHP/5.6.8 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Nov 12 12:21:16.025061 2015] [core:notice] [pid 6961] AH00094: Command line: '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/httpd -E /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/logs/error_log -D SSL -D PHP'